# American renting a car in the UK - Can I rent from the .co.uk site?

Tags: budget, car-rentals

I live in the United States, and I'm traveling to the UK with my family this spring. We're planning to rent a car at Heathrow for 6 days, but I'm finding wildly different prices when I look at the UK site compared to the US site (for example, avis.co.uk and avis.com). For example, an automatic small SUV can be booked for 557.84 GBP at avis.co.uk, which is just under $700 USD using current conversion rates. The same vehicle at avis.com is more than twice as much at $1,491! The USA site asks for country of residency, where the UK site does not.

So, to finally get around to my question, is there any problem with renting from avis.co.uk (or budget.co.uk, enterprise.co.uk, etc) as an American resident, instead of a .com site?

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/133765/car-rental-prices-different-for-foreigners

Comment: Check that the bundled insurance is similar or equivalent.

Answer (score 6):

The top-level domains of websites (.com, .uk, .int, etc.) do not have any legal significance for their users. Whether you’re allowed by a company to use a particular service depends on the terms of use for that service, and can’t be generalised to other companies.

Anecdotally, I have rented cars from many companies in many countries, and in the few situations where a particular residency was required, the company was not at all subtle in announcing that requirement.

Comment: The Avis.co.uk site specifies (in their FAQs) documents required by prospective US renters.